# High exponent numbers with scipy.stats functions

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, double, precision

I have a set of number that can get very small, from `1e-100`, to `1e-700` and lower. The precision doesn't matter as much as the exponent.
I can load such numbers just fine using Pandas by simply providing `Decimal` as a converter for all such numeric columns.

The problem is, even if I use Python's `Decimal`, I just can't use `scipy.stats.chi2.isf` and similar functions since their C code explicitly uses `double`.
A possible workaround is that I can use log10 of the numbers. The problem here is that although there is `logsf` function, for `chi2` it's implemented as just `log(sf(...))`, and will, therefore, fail when `sf` returns 0 where it should've returned something like `1e-600`. And for `isf` there is no such log function at all.

I wanted to know if there is any way to work with such numbers without resolving to writing all these functions myself for Decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write the expression for logsf directly using logs of gamma functions from `scipy.special` (gammaln, loggamma). And you could send a pull request implementing the logsf for the chi-square distribution.